# How can I jump through an advertisement from a particular IP address in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, ip, blocking, advertisements

I use Firefox (under Linux/Ubuntu) with a lot of anti-advertisement extensions, like [Adblock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus), [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript), Ghosty, etc.

I found this IP address, *220.191.158.69*, always in the list of NoScript, and I want to ban this IP address. I have checked it and searched it. It is from a China telecom advertisement.

I guess NoScript can ban this IP address already, but *when* I do not allow that IP address, sometimes a webpage can not be loaded at first time. I need to refresh two or more times. I hate it...

So I hope there are some way or browser extensions or script can jump through this specific IP address.

Comment: *> When I do not allow that IP, sometimes a webpage can not be loaded at first time, I need to refresh two or more times. I hate it...*   What might be happening is that the page is trying to load a file from the ad server, so when you block it, the page has trouble loading. You could try using an IP blocker like [PeerBlock](https://www.google.com/search?q=ip+blocker) to block all connections to the IP altogether.

Comment: In future, PLEASE include your OS/Distro and other relevant information in the question.

Comment: Re *"Ghosty"*: Do you mean *[Ghostery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostery)*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a GUI for it in your distro, but i believe its a simple matter of adding a firewall rule - something like `/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s 10.10.10.10 -j DROP` should do the trick - you can see more [examples on howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/wiki/Using_Iptables_on_Linux#Blocking_a_Single_IP_Address). I believe you need to save the firewall rules as well but thats fairly distro specific.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your [*hosts* file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) (it exists in Windows and Unix operating systems).
In Windows, it is usually at `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc`.

Add the following text at the end of the file:

```
    220.191.158.69        localhost
```

Save it. Reboot to be more sure... And try problematic pages.

Comment: I'm using Linux, I add this line into `/etc/hosts` file, but this does not work. (I rebooted my system)

Comment: hosts only works for domain names - it just overrides DNS, so won't work here.